# Identify protractor test failed assertions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

When a protractor test fails, how can I find which test failed?

For example, all it displays is: 
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure

If I had multiple assertions and failures, I would not know which one failed.

I looked in the documentation and also in the live selenium webdriver trace, but did not see how I would know which assertion or test failed.

EDIT: looks like it was there the whole time and I didn't read

Failures:

1) angularjs homepage todo list should add a todo
   Message:
     Expected false to be true.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Failed expectation
    at [object Object]. (/Users/jacques.fu/projects/protractor/todo-spec.js:11:75)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `protractor` should give you a stacktrace on which line the expectation failed or an error happened. But, what I also find useful is a `TerminalReporter` jasmine reporter from [`jasmine-reporters`](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters). Add this to `onPrepare()` to make it work:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.TerminalReporter({
    verbosity: 3,
    color: true,
    showStack: true
}));
```